# Mono v.4 old version

Tags: mono

I try to install a server using Mono v.4.

The current version is 5.2.

I reached for the sources.list mono debian/snapshots/X.XX.X as recommanded
(where X.XX.X = 4.0.4, 4.8.0, 4.9.0 or 5.0.0) but it always installs the 3.2.8 or 5.0.0.100 anyway.

Has somebody the mirror to a mono 4.XX.X, please ?
Or other solution to access the mono v.4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the sources of all versions of Mono.
I let them here for those who can need.

[List of Mono versions](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/)

[Sources downloads.](https://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/)

Hope that will help.